# How to print a grid from coordinates like 0, 0 in a MapSet in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I'm learning Elixir by building a simple tic-tac-toe game. Right now the way I set it up is to have the players selection cell on the board as `{col, row}` so `{0, 0}`, `{1, 2}`, etc. and all the moves are stored in a `MapSet` called turns.

```
%TTT{turns: %{x: MapSet.new, o: MapSet.new}, last_player: :player}
```

I have finished implementing the basic game logic but I'm having a hard time trying to build a simple command line representation of the game particularly in displaying the current state of the board. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For coordinate based boards, I usually create the board as a map with {col, row} keys.

Here is a sample board with a print function:

```
defmodule Ttt do
  def new_board do
    for col <- 1..3, row <- 1..3, into: %{}, do: {{col, row}, " "}
  end

  def put(board, {col, row}, val) do
    put(board, col, row, val)
  end

  def put(board, col, row, val), do: Map.put(board, {col, row}, val)

  def fill(board, list, which) do
    Enum.reduce(list, board, fn point, acc -> put(acc, point, which) end)
  end

  def fill_example_1(board) do
    xs = [{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}]
    ys = [{2, 1}, {3, 1}, {1, 2}]

    board
    |> fill(xs, "X")
    |> fill(ys, "O")
  end

  def print(board) do
    for row <- 1..3 do
      for col <- 1..3 do
        " " <> board[{col, row}]
      end
      |> Enum.join(" |")
    end
    |> Enum.join("\n---+---+---\n")
    |> IO.puts()
  end

  def run do
    new_board()
    |> fill_example_1()
    |> print
  end
end
```

And the output:

```
 iex(2)> Ttt.run()
 X | O | O
---+---+---
 O | X |
---+---+---
   |   | X
:ok
```

Answer (score 2):

@Steve Pallen gave a great answer, however I would like to point out the perks of using a [**`GenServer`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html) instead of a regular module: it will allow the use of `handle_info` callback to display the board. This feature of elixir has many advantages:

- The display is **permanently** and **automatically** refreshed.
- It's easier to **distribute**: for example, if each player plays on his own computer, no need to call a function in order to check if the other player has played: it automatically appears on the display thanks to the `GenServer`.
- You can use a supervisor, and take full advantage of the **let it crash** philosophy of elixir

The code below can give you an idea of how to do it:

```
defmodule Tictactoe do
    use GenServer

    def start_link(opts), do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, opts)

    def init(:ok) do
        schedule_work()
        {:ok, state}
    end


    # ...
    # game code + print function defined in Steve Pallen's answer
    # ...

    def handle_info(:work, state) do
      print(state) # use function defined by Steve Pallen above
      schedule_work()
      {:noreply, state}
    end

    # function used by the callback to refresh display every 100ms
    defp schedule_work(), do: Process.send_after(self(), :work, 100)

end
```

An example of a tictactoe using this system is available [**here**](https://github.com/ripertn/tictactoe).